# XLS decision table doesn't work on 8.32.0.Final

Tags: drools, java-17

I tried to run the latest version of drools (8.32.0.Final) in a java project where I have as a decision table an xls file where base on some condition to return the data from that xls.
After I created the POJO object with some data and insert in the engine the field where I expect to be set is null.

The code to create a KieSession is:

```
KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("path to the xls file"));
KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
kb.buildAll();
KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
kContainer.newKieSession();
```

I tried also providing a Resource but same result:

```
KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem().write(dt);
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();
KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();
KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
kContainer.newKieSession();
```

Decision table looks like this:
First line contains a rule set.
Second line contains import object model followed by RuleTabel with the specification.

NOTE: If I tried to convert the xls to drl, it is converted correctly.

Specification:
JAVA 17
kie-ci, drools-decisiontables, drools-core, drools-compiler version 8.32.0.Final

I expected that after I run this on an object to set a specific field on the input object.

```
kieSession.insert(depositRequest);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
kieSession.dispose();
```

But the expected fields were null.

Could you please anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try adding an `AgendaEventListener` to see if the rules are even firing. Most of the times, the problem is not that the rules don't work, but that they are not even present in the `KieBase`.

Comment: Hi @EstebanAliverti Thank you very much I solved with the bellow solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, you missed to have a file name ending with `.drl.xls`, `.drl.xlsx`, or `.drl.csv`.

Tested with: https://github.com/tarilabs/demo-so75716587

and that works for me.

We're adding explitic mention in the documentation as we speak.

Comment: adding doc explicit mentions with https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/pull/5091

Comment: @mihai don't forget to mark as Answered if helpful, glad it helped